# What does this Imagedraw code line for pixel color setting mean?

Tags: python-3.x, image, colors, pixel

I am trying to color a pixel of an image (Pillow ImageDraw) according to an integer  property,say m, of that pixel at ix,iy coordinates. I came across this line of code in one plotting example and this gives beautiful results.

```
    bitmap = Image.new("RGB", (WIDTH,HEIGHT), "white")
    pix=bitmap.load()
```

....obtain m value for the pixel ix,iy

```
    pix[ix,iy] = (m>>21)+(m<<10)+m*8
```

I have searched documentation to see what this means, but couldn't find any. I think the inequality sign has something to do with shifting bits. Can someone expalin? Thanks

Comment: Where did you find this gem? Please add the surrounding code necessary to set `m` and run it. If you know that it works, you surely know what it is supposed to do and also what it produces so why not share that info and make it easier for folk to assist you?

Comment: This line can be found in the code for plotting a Julia Fractal in https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/julia-fractal-python/ It is a very economic and powerful, but dont understand how this works at all.